# Different table view cell row heights for different size classes?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

How can I change this UITableViewController custom class to dynamically change the height of the Table View Cells? I have specified different font sizes for the iPad and iPhone size classes.
(This is a continuation of a previous discussion with @rdelmar)

```
#import "CREWFoodWaterList.h"

@interface CREWFoodWaterList ()

@end

@implementation CREWFoodWaterList

#define VIEW_NAME @"FoodWaterList" // add to database for this view and notes view
#define VIEW_DESCRIPTION @"Food Water - items to keep available" // to add to the database
#define RETURN_NC @"NCSuggestedContentsMenu" // where to return to when complete processing should be specified there

#define NOTES_TITLE @"Food and Water Notes" // pass to notes VC
#define THIS_NC @"NCFoodWaterList" // pass to next VC (so returns to the NC for this view)

- (IBAction)changedSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {

if (sender.tag == 0) {
    [self saveSwitch: @"switchWater" toValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on]];
} else if (sender.tag == 1) {
    [self saveSwitch: @"switchCanned" toValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on]];
} else if (sender.tag == 2) {
    [self saveSwitch: @"switchComfort" toValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on]];
} else if (sender.tag == 3) {
    [self saveSwitch: @"switchSpecial" toValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on]];
}
} // end of changedSwitch

-(void)loadSavedSwitches {
// now set the switches to previously stored values

NSNumber *switchValue;

switchValue = [self getSwitch: @"switchWater"];

if ([switchValue intValue] == 0) {
    self.switchWater.on = NO;
} else {
    self.switchWater.on = YES;
}
self.textWater.text = [self getDescription:@"switchWater"];

switchValue = [self getSwitch: @"switchCanned"];
if ([switchValue intValue] == 0) {
    self.switchCanned.on = NO;
} else {
    self.switchCanned.on = YES;
}
self.textCanned.text = [self getDescription:@"switchCanned"];


switchValue = [self getSwitch: @"switchComfort"];
if ([switchValue intValue] == 0) {
    self.switchComfort.on = NO;
} else {
    self.switchComfort.on = YES;
}
self.textComfort.text = [self getDescription:@"switchComfort"];
//    self.textComfort.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

switchValue = [self getSwitch: @"switchSpecial"];
if ([switchValue intValue] == 0) {
    self.switchSpecial.on = NO;
} else {
    self.switchSpecial.on = YES;
}
self.textSpecial.text = [self getDescription:@"switchSpecial"];

}

- (void) createNewSwitches {
//  set create all switches and set to off

[self newSwitch: @"switchWater" toValue:@"At least three litres of bottle water per person per day"];
[self newSwitch: @"switchCanned" toValue:@"Canned foods, dried goods and staples"];
[self newSwitch: @"switchComfort" toValue:@"Comfort foods"];
[self newSwitch: @"switchSpecial" toValue:@"Food for infants, seniors and special diets"];
}
// COMMON Methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// set font size for table headers

[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSString *myModel =  [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSInteger nWords = 1;
NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0, nWords);
NSArray *firstWord = [[myModel componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] subarrayWithRange:wordRange];
NSString *obj = [firstWord objectAtIndex:0];

if ([obj isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26]];}
else if ([obj isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
};

[defaults setObject:NOTES_TITLE forKey: @"VCtitle"]; // pass to notes VC
[defaults setObject:VIEW_NAME forKey: @"VCname"]; // pass to notes VC to use to store notes
[defaults setObject:THIS_NC forKey: @"CallingNC"];    // get previous CallingNC and save it for use to return to in doneAction

[self initializeView];
} // end of viewDidLoad

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self.tableView reloadData]; // this was necessary to have the cells size correctly when the table view first appeared
}

- (void) initializeView {
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"View" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@)", VIEW_NAME];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) { // create new view instance
    NSManagedObject * newView;
    newView = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"View" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newView setValue:VIEW_NAME forKey:@"viewName"];
    [newView setValue:VIEW_DESCRIPTION forKey:@"viewDescription"];

    //  create all switches and set to off
    [self createNewSwitches];
}
//  load all switches
[self loadSavedSwitches];
} // end of initializeView

// create a new switch
- (void) newSwitch:(NSString*)switchName toValue:(NSString*)switchDescription {
NSError *error = nil;
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject * newSwitch;

newSwitch = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Switch" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newSwitch setValue:VIEW_NAME forKey:@"viewName"];
[newSwitch setValue:switchName forKey:@"switchName"];
[newSwitch setValue:switchDescription forKey:@"switchDescription"];
[newSwitch setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"switchValue"];
if (! [context save:&error])
    // NSLog(@"**** START entering %@",VIEW_NAME);
    NSLog(@"newSwitch Couldn't save new data! Error:%@", [error description]);
} // end of newSwitch

// read existing switch settings
- (NSNumber *) getSwitch:(NSString*)switchName {
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Switch" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@) AND (switchName = %@)", VIEW_NAME, switchName];
[request setPredicate:pred];

// Execute Fetch Request
NSManagedObjectContext * matches = nil;
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *objects = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
if (fetchError) {
};

NSNumber *switchValue;

if (! [objects count] == 0) {
    matches = objects [0];
    switchValue = [matches valueForKey : @"switchValue"];
}

return switchValue;
} // end of getSwitch

- (NSString *) getDescription:(NSString*)switchName {
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Switch" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@) AND (switchName = %@)", VIEW_NAME, switchName];
[request setPredicate:pred];

// Execute Fetch Request
NSManagedObjectContext * matches = nil;
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *objects = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
if (fetchError) {
    // NSLog(@"**** START entering %@",VIEW_NAME);(@"getSwitch Fetch error:%@", fetchError); // no
};

NSString *switchDescription;

if (! [objects count] == 0) {
    matches = objects [0];
    switchDescription = [matches valueForKey : @"switchDescription"];
}
return switchDescription;
} // end of getDescription


- (void)saveSwitch:(NSString*)switchName toValue:(NSNumber*)newSwitchValue {
CREWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Switch" inManagedObjectContext:context]; // get switch entity

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(viewName = %@) AND (switchName = %@)", VIEW_NAME, switchName ];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

if (![objects count] == 0) {
    matches = objects[0];
}

[matches setValue:newSwitchValue forKey:@"switchValue"];

if (! [context save:&fetchError])
    // NSLog(@"**** START entering %@",VIEW_NAME);
    NSLog(@"saveSwitch Couldn't save data! Error:%@", [fetchError description]); // perhaps this can be Done later
} // end of saveSwitch

// set alternate cells to different colors

- (UIColor *)getUIColorObjectFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
// Convert hex string to an integer
unsigned int hexint = [self intFromHexString:hexStr];

// Create color object, specifying alpha as well
UIColor *color =
[UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255
                green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255
                 blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255
                alpha:alpha];

return color;
}
// Helper method..

- (unsigned int)intFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr
{
unsigned int hexInt = 0;

// Create scanner
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];

// Tell scanner to skip the # character
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];

// Scan hex value
[scanner scanHexInt:&hexInt];

return hexInt;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *grayishCyan = @"#a3c9ca";
NSString *grayishRed = @"#caa4a3";
UIColor *colorCyan = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:grayishCyan alpha:.9];
UIColor *colorPink = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:grayishRed alpha:.9];
//    // NSLog(@"**** START entering %@",VIEW_NAME);(@"UIColor: %@", colorPink);

if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = colorCyan;
}
else {
    cell.backgroundColor = colorPink;
    }
}

- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
//        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:RETURN_NC];  // previous Navigation controller
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
};


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Comment: This is a huge amount of code, most of which has nothing to do with your problem. Self-sizing cells require what you've already done in viewDidLoad, and having the proper constraints on your cell. It would be more useful to see just viewDidLoad, all the table view data source and delegate methods, and a description of the cell and its constraints. You should also describe what result your current code is giving you, and what's wrong with that.

Comment: Sorry about the code ... I wasn't sure which part you would find relevant. The problem is the height of the tableviewcell does not seem to have an option to change based on the size class, so my experience (as a very inexperienced -aka amateur - coder) I have to specify a height that is the right size to fit the iPhone and iPad textView heights.

Comment: The height of the cell, when you use self-sizing cells is calculated from the height of the  cell's subviews -- this isn't directly related to using different font sizes for different size classes. That should be solved with what I said in the answer to your other question. You don't specify the height of the text view at all, you need to turn off its scrolling, and give it constraints that pin it to the top and bottom of the cell (or to other views above and below it).

Comment: Excuse me if I am being very obtuse. I have configured the textViews to be pinned to the top and bottom of the cell. They do not use scrolling. By saying I don't need to specify the height of the textView are you saying I don't need a height constraint? And finally are you saying I still need to use the self-sizing code that you discussed in the previous question?

Comment: Yes, you still need to use the self-sizing cells (which you're already doing in viewDidLoad), and yes, I'm saying that you should not have a height constraint on the text view -- it's height will be determined by the size of its text, as long as its width is constrained.

Comment: Since my tableview uses STATIC cells I think that is the cause of my problems. I am going to start a new question with that emphasized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78658/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-patriciaw).