# Is it possible to have different STATIC tableviewcell heights for different size classes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, size-classes

This app uses static cells extensively. I've posted other questions around this but did not specify that I am using static cells. The code is posted in [Different table view cell row heights for different size classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424623/different-table-view-cell-row-heights-for-different-size-classes?noredirect=1#comment48937722_30424623)

In summary here is the situation:
I am using custom UITableView classes to load data in the UITextViews in UITextViewCells.
The app is adaptive and there appears to be no way to change the height of the tableviewcells for different size classes.
Is it possible to do this for static cells?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use self-sizing cells with a static table view. I would advise you to switch to using dynamic prototypes, and then you can use the technique I gave in my answer to your other question (using self-sizing cells and setting different fonts for different size classes in the storyboard). There is nothing that you can do with a static table view cell, that you can't also do with a dynamic one. You still make all the cells you need in the storyboard, and then dequeue the correct one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` based on the `indexPath`.